# Import CSV using monetdb from daemon

Tags: csv, monetdb

Is there a way to do this without having to fire up an instance?

Answer (score 1):

The monetdb tool manages (creates, starts, stops, ...) the databases but not the data that is stored in them.

In principle, you could load data without starting mserver by directly editing the underlying data structures. Columns (bats) are stored as memory mapped files and you could edit them manually using a program you wrote yourself. However, you'd be messing with the internal structures of monet which is not a good idea.

Just out of curiosity: why would you want to do this? What is it that you want to achieve? Would you mind posing a second question stating your real problem?